# Java GC Monitoring on Linux

Tags: linux, java, monitoring

On Windowssystems I use jvisualvm to monitor the GC activity of my programs. Are there any similar tools for linux to do so? I acces the server via putty (ssh), so graphical tools are not supported, but i would appriciate it if it had some kind of ascii art to display the heap etc.

I am thankful for every suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could alse use JVisualVM in your Linux box, assuming you 
- turn on X11Forwarding in sshd config (Linux side) and putty 
- start a X-server on your PC. (you can consider using Xming or cygwin's xwin available in xinit package)

Comment: I thought about that too. But i am sure there are other ways to do it. I dont wanna have any graphical tools to do the monitoring job.